# Real json value is more different then expected value using javascript / node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

I am destructing the data from the function

```
let { destructValue } = require("./destructValue.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

function retrunValues(data) {
  fs.readdir("./userData", (err, files) => {
    if (err) throw console.log(err.message);
    else {
      files.forEach(async (file) => {
        fs.readFile(`./userData/${file}`, (err, data) => {
          destructValue(data);
          let jsonObject = {};
          if (destructValue(data).length !== 0) {
            jsonObject = {
              name: data.name,
              value: [...destructValue(data)],
            };
            console.log(jsonObject);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
}
```

so after doing console.log(jsonObject) I am getting this values

```
{
 name: "Tomas",
 value:[{
  age: "21",
  address: "New York"
 }]
}
{
 name: "Jerry",
 value:[{
  age: "22",
  address: "Tokyo"
 }]
}
```

this output look fine to me as this was the expected output so I tried to call jsonObject into new schema like this

```
let { destructValue } = require("./destructValue.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

function retrunValues(data) {
  fs.readdir("./userData", (err, files) => {
    if (err) throw console.log(err.message);
    else {
      files.forEach(async (file) => {
        fs.readFile(`./userData/${file}`, (err, data) => {
          destructValue(data);
          let jsonObject = {},
            testingObject = {};
          if (destructValue(data).length !== 0) {
            jsonObject = {
              name: data.name,
              value: [...destructValue(data)],
            };
          }

          testingObject = {
            default: "default value",
            got: jsonObject,
          };

          console.log(testingObject);
        });
      });
    }
  });
}
```

so after doing console.log(testingObject) I am getting this value

```
{ default: 'defaultObject'}
{ default: 'defaultObject'}
{ default: 'defaultObject',
  name: "Tomas",
  value:[{
   age: "21",
   address: "New York"
  }]
}
{ default: 'defaultObject'}
{ default: 'defaultObject'}
{ default: 'defaultObject',
  name: "Jerry",
  value:[{
   age: "22",
   address: "Tokyo"
  }]
}
```

As I was not expecting this output as my expected output was like this

```
[
  {
    "default": "defaultObject",
    "got": [
      {
        "name": "Tomas",
        "value": [{ "age": "21", "address": "New York" }]
      },
      {
        "name": "Jerry",
        "value": [{ "age": "22", "address": "Tokyo" }]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

but I am not getting the expected value and I don't know where it went wrong how can I achieve my expected value

### destructValue.js

```
const {age,address}=require(valueGot.js);

function destructValue(data){
 const destructSchema=[];
 for(const value of data){
  switch(value.userDetails){
   case "age":
    destructSchema.push(age(data));
   break;
   case "address":
    destructSchema.push(address(data));
   break;
  }
 }
return destructSchema;
}

module.exports={destructValue}
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `./destructeValue.js`?

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle I have added the contents of `./destructeValue.js`

Comment: Hi Vikas, are you using a library like React or any others in your project? I think we need to know what is calling the `returnValues()` function, as we can see from your console output that even in your first example it is actually being called twice, since it writes two separate objects to the console.

Comment: It is unclear, what is it you need to be answered, can you try to reformulate your question? It would help if you start by explaining what kind of a data structure you have, and how you would want it to look like, and then post the solution you currently have for it, it will help others understand you better, and help you get an answer faster

Comment: hi @SamerMurad I have updated my question for more clear understandable :)

Comment: Hi @BillyHudson I had removed some part of code to avoid stack warning but I have added that back I hope its know clear understandable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below. Save your results into an array and when you have finished going through the files, you output your results.

**Edit**: I added a filter for the results, but haven't tested. It should only add destructed data that hasn't been added before.

```
let { destructValue } = require("./destructValue.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

function filterAgainstExisting(existing, check) {
  return check.reduce((carry, value, index, array) => {
    //Check if value exists - not generic, catered to your needs
    if (existing[value.name] && existing[value.name].age == value.value[0].age && existing[value.name].address == value.value[0].address) {
      return carry;
    }
    
    existing[value.name] = value;
    carry.push(value);
    return carry;
  }, []);
}

function retrunValues(data) {
  fs.readdir("./userData", (err, files) => {
    if (err) throw console.log(err.message);
    else {
      let jsonArray = [];
      let jsonObject = {};
      files.forEach(async (file) => {
        fs.readFile(`./userData/${file}`, (err, data) => {
          let destructedData = destructValue(data);
          if (destructedData.length !== 0) {
            jsonArray.push({
              name: data.name,
              value: [...this.filterAgainstExisting(jsonObject, destructedData)],
            });
          }
        });
      });

      const testingObject = [{
        default: "defaultObject",
        got: jsonArray,
      }];

      console.log(testingObject);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi @OwChallie its working as expectantly but the jsonArray value get repeated many times is there any possible way I can get always unique value ?

Comment: @Vikas Not sure what you mean exactly, but if there are duplicates in jsonArray, you can filter them out. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing *requrie*

`let {destructValue} = requrie("./destructeValue.js");`

to *require*

`let {destructValue} = require("./destructeValue.js");`